# How do I use the ADDS function in assembly code?

Tags: assembly, terminal, arm

I am trying to learn assembly language, and am trying to use the ADDS function to add numbers from the first 3 registers into register 0.

So far I have this:

```
.global _start
_start:
MOV R1, #5
MOV R2, #6
MOV R3, #7
ADDS R4, R1, R2
ADDS R0, R4, R3
SWI 0
```

I get the error of:

ld:add.s: file format not recognized; treating as linker script

ld:add.s:1: syntax error

I do not know what a linker script is and why it is treating my code as such, I just ran another assembly code with just the MOV functions and it ran just fine. Is it something with the way I am writing the ADDS functions maybe? Or am I not starting my file right? I am running it on my terminal with

```
 as -o add.o add.s
```

to assemble it, which works just fine, but when I try and link it with

```
ld -o add.o add.s
```

It throws the error. Any help would be appreciated. If it makes any difference the file is being held on my Raspberry Pi. Thank you!

Comment: Your linker invocation is wrong.  To the linker, you need to pass the name of the object file and the name of the binary, e.g. `ld -o add add.o`.

Comment: @fuz Hi thank you so much!! It is linked finally but now when I try to run it it says there is an illegal instruction sadly. Working on that part now. Thanks for spotting my error though! <3

Comment: The problem is that your code just kinda ends.  The processor does not know that your program ends, it just tries to execute whatever comes after it in memory as code, leading to a crash.  To fix this, you must perform an exit system call.  I see that you might have tried to do this, but you forgot to set up the arguments and system call number.

Answer (score 0):

Linker create ELF file . You must use it this way:

```
ld -o add.elf add.o
```